# Visual Studio 2019, Android app doesn't start

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I've just created an Android app with Xamarin Form. If I start the app on a real device, the app doesn't start and I have the following error:

> Trying to initialize the debugger with options:
>   --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:29266,server=y,embedding=1
>
> Accepted stdout connection: -1
>
> Error accepting stdout and stderr
>   (127.0.0.1:29267): Address already in use

I tried to add **d8 Dex compiler** and under **Linking** I selected **Sdk Assemblies Only** without results.

[image: Settings]

Any idea? Thank you

### Update

I think the issue is on **Use Fast Deployment (debug mode only)**. If it is checked, the app doesn't work. In the code you can find this line:

> <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>false</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>

Comment: Quit all the emulators, visual studio and start again.

Comment: yes, I also have this issue when I use adb over wifi/LAN if I select fast deployment